# Calculating the diagonal proportion (total Accuracy) of table in R

Tags: r

I have the following table:

```
>a

scores   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
     0 421 409  31  10   1   3   1   0   0   0
     1 100 113  17  12   2   0   0   0   0   0
> str (a)
 'table' int [1:2, 1:10] 421 100 409 113 31 17 10 12 1 2 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ scores: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  ..$       : chr [1:10] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...

> dput(a)
structure(c(421L, 409L, 309L, 113L, 31L, 17L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(2L, 10L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    scores = c("0", "1"), c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
    "7", "8", "9")), .Names = c("scores", "")), class = "table")
```

I would like to calculate the sum for each row the percentage of the diagonal proportion value:

```
(421/(421+409+31+10 + 1  + 3 +  1)) + (113 / (100 + 113 + 17 + 12 + 2))
```

Is there a more efficient way to calculate it than using `rowSums(a)` and using loop for the calculating the diagonal value divided by the sum of each row?

Comment: The calculation is not very clear

Comment: (a[1,1]/sum (row a[1] )) + (a[2,2]/ sum(row[2]))....

Comment: How about `sum(diag(a)/rowSums(a))`? btw you should share your sample data using `dput(a)`.